# LTspice IV How can I get round value with 4 point digit?

Tags: ltspice

First of all sorry if the title aren't fully describe what I want since I'm not native Eng speaker ,

In short I start taring my self on electronic using **LTspice IV** , since I don't want high precision output values I end up seeing xxxx.xxxxxx somthing mV which I don't need and makes diagram read so difficult(I had to decrease  font size to see the values )

[image: LTspice IV]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the current label and edit the expression to display to

`round(V(n001))`

for no decimals, and to

`round(V(n001)*10)/10`

for 1 decimal, etc.

You can use "$" as well, which is an aliases of the current selected voltage node.

To make the value automatically changing and always showing at most X <strike>significant</strike> digits <sup>(1)</sup>, you can use

`round(pow(10,YYY-round(log10($))) * $ )/ pow(10,YYY-round(log10($)))`

where YYY is X-1.

e.g.

`round( pow(10,2-round( log10( abs($) ) ) ) * $ ) / pow(10,2-round( log10( abs($) ) ) )`

will show the voltage in 2+1 = 3 digits.

For currents, you only can use `I(..)`, so, e.g.

`round( pow(10,2-round( log10( abs(I(R1)) ) ) ) * I(R1) ) / pow(10,2-round( log10( abs(I(R1)) ) ) )`

The `abs(...)` makes sure the `log10( )` picks the correct magnitude of the value, independent of the sign of the value.

To make the equation even more perfect, zero values should be covered as well, making the equation even bigger and more complex:

`if(abs(I(R1))>0, round( pow(10,2-round( log10( abs(I(R1))+1pA ) ) ) * I(R1) ) / pow(10,2-round( log10( abs(I(R1))+1pA ) ) ), 0)`

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Sadly, LTspice eats the trailing zeros...

Comment: thank bu it's return it to fixed volt (instead of  `833.333333mV` ) its show me 1v I want it looks like `833mV` or `833.33mV`..........alright i use `round(V(n001)*10)/10`and give me values on mV , Just want to ask how to make permit to the program ,

Comment: @SalemF I'm not sure what *Just want to ask how to make permit to the program*, did you mean permanent? Please find updated answer and check the option that keeps showing X digits for any simulated value. Maybe this covers the 'permanent'?

Comment: Alright everything works fine , I don't know, but sometimes I got pA (Pico Ampere) value on some nodes , are this amount of current important since when I use round with it LTspice return 0A , I want mA values if possible until now I don't know ho to add Amps node(label)

Comment: @SalemF It's quite possible you get these small values due to the currents being negative. I've updated the equation by using ```abs(…)``` when taking the log10 of it.